# Chaining tasks with continuation and run parallel task afterward

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

**The work flow of the parallel tasks**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luRnu.png]

I am hoping to get help on the problem I am facing. So the problem is that I am running parallel tasks to search through folders for files. Each task entails identifying files and add it to a array of files. Next, wait until every task completes so that files are gathered up, then perform sorting on the results. Next, process the sorted file independently, by running one task per file to read through it to get a matching pattern back. The final stage is to aggregate all the results together in human readable format and display it in a user-friendly way.

**So the question is that I want to chain the tasks in a proper way that does not blocks the UI thread. I would like to be able to cancel everything at any stage the program is at.**

To sum it up:

Stage 1: Find files by searching through folders. Each task search recursively through a folder tree.

Stage 2: Sort all the files found and clean up duplicates

Stage 3: Start new tasks to process the files independently. Each task opens a file and search for matching pattern.

Stage 4: Aggregate result from every single file search into one giant result set and make it pretty for human to read.

```
     List<Task> myTasks = new List<Task>();

// ==== stage 1 ======
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           string directoryName = directories[i];

           Task t = new Task(() =>
           {
              FindFiles(directoryName);
           });

           myTasks.Add(t);
            t.Start();
        }

// ==== stage 2 ====
        Task sortTask = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(myTasks.ToArray(), (t) =>
        {
           if(_fileResults.Count > 1) {
              // sort the files and remove any duplicates
           }
        });

        sortTask.Wait();

// ==== stage 3 ====
        Task tt = new Task(() =>
        {
             Parallel.For(0, _fileResults.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, CancellationToken = token, TaskScheduler = _taskScheduler },
                    (i, loopstate) => {
              // 1. open file
              // 2. read file
              // 3. read file line by line
              }
        }

// == stage 4 === 
        tt.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
           // 1. aggregate the file results into one giant result set
           // 2. display the giant result set in human readable format
        }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

      tt.start();
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever be using the `Task` constructor.  If you want to create a task that represents executing a delegate, use `Task.Run` to create and start such a task.

Comment: You shouldn't have each of those tasks mutating a `List` to add their results.  `List` isn't thread safe, so this won't necessarily work.  Have each task return the value it produces when it has computed its result, and have the continuation(s) access that result through the `Task` API.

Comment: I am using lock and interlock to put a locking on the shared object. The shared object being the result set.

Comment: Not in the code you posted you aren't.  And even so, you shouldn't do that.  You should have each of the tasks set their result to the value they're computing.  It represents the semantics *much* better, it allows the code to be modularized and effectively analyzed in isolation, and it'll also be faster as you're not introducing dependances between each of the tasks entirely unnecessarily.

Comment: I agree with your point. There's a chance I will change it accordingly once I figure out how to chain the task together. The major problem I am having is on figuring out how to chain the tasks properly together. Have you look at the my flow diagram - http://i.stack.imgur.com/luRnu.png

Answer (score 1):

Don't synchronously wait for any of the tasks to finish.  If any of those operations need to take place after a previously created task, add that work as a continuation of that task instead.

Comment: I realized that. But, the objective is to have all the task complete their searches so that I can sort the final result set.

Comment: @EricLiu And the way to do that is to do whatever work you need done using those values as continuations of the tasks creating the intermediate values, rather than synchronously blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Can you elaborate with a quick example. Much appreciated.

Comment: @EricLiu You've already shown that you know how to add a continuation to a task in the code in the OP.  Just do that for all 3 of the continuation operations you have, instead of doing that for 2 out of the 3 and synchronously blocking for one of them.  If you want to see an example, just look at your own code for your last stage.

Comment: Something like this ?
                var a = new Task(() => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("start")).ContinueWith((t) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(t.Id.ToString() + " completed")).ContinueWith((t) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(t.Id.ToString() + " completed");

Comment: @EricLiu That's one way to add a continuation, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `async/await` feature - By the sounds of your question, it's the perfect match for your needs.  Here's a quick attempt at your problem using it:

```
try
{
    List<Task<File[]>> stage1Tasks = new List<Task<File[]>>();

    // ==== stage 1 ======
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string directoryName = directories[i];

        Task<File[]> t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return FindFiles(directoryName);
        },
            token);

        stage1Tasks.Add(t);
    }

    File[][] files = await Task.WhenAll(stage1Tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Flatten files.
    File[] _fileResults = files.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();

    // ==== stage 2 ====
    Task<File[]> sortFilesTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (_fileResults.Count > 1)
        {
            // sort the files and remove any duplicates
            return _fileResults.Reverse().ToArray();
        }
    },
        token);

    File[] _sortedFileResults = await sortFilesTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

    // ==== stage 3 ====
    Task<SomeResult[]> tt = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        SomeResult[] results = new SomeResult[_sortedFileResults.Length];
        Parallel.ForEach(_sortedFileResults,
            new ParallelOptions {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
                CancellationToken = token,
                TaskScheduler = _taskScheduler
            },
            (i, loopstate) =>
            {
                // 1. open file
                // 2. read file
                // 3. read file line by line
                results[i] = new SomeResult( /* here goes your results for each file */);
            });
        return results;
    },
        token);

    SomeResult[] theResults = await tt.ConfigureAwait(false);


    // == stage 4 === 
    // 1. aggregate the file results into one giant result set
    // 2. display the giant result set in human readable format
    // ....

}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    // some task has been cancelled...
}
```

Comment: I would also like to be able to use cancellationToken to exit the program at any stage. From time to time between tasks, i want to jump back to the UI thread to update the progress.

Comment: Nonetheless, I am going to give your code a try. I am not familiar with async, it does seems promising. If I get stuck, I will let you know. Thanks James.

Comment: my variable (defined out of view in my sample) called `token` is a `CancellationToken` that you can use to cancel any of the tasks you can see.  The catch block will then be fired.